# My caml query not working properly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

What is wrong about below caml query?

```
    <Where>
    <And><Or>
    <Neq><FieldRef Name='NumberOfPcsRemaining' />
    <Value  Type='Calculated'>0</Value></Neq>
    <IsNull><FieldRef Name='OutForDeliveryDateTime' /></IsNull>
    </Or>
    <And>
    <Includes><FieldRef Name='ServiceType'  /> 
    <Value Type='LookupMulti'>Delivery</Value></Includes>
    <And>
    <Neq><FieldRef Name='BBAStatus'  />
    <Value Type='Text'>BBA not Completed</Value> </Neq>
    <And> 
    <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='IncidentReport'  /></IsNotNull>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='OkToDeliver' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
    </And>
    </And>
    </And> 
    </And>
    </Where>
```

It seems below  part is always coming true even it has value.

```
  <IsNull><FieldRef Name='OutForDeliveryDateTime' /></IsNull>
```

Comment: Try using U2U Caml builder/helper  http://www.u2u.be/Software   or https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you. I've found the reason. I have changed Calculated field's type to number. And it works now.